# Frequent audio dropouts on bluetooth, is it possibe to increase BT emission levels

Tags: bluetooth, 9.0-pie, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Note 7 and AKG Y500 headphones. I experience very frequent audio drop-outs unless I keep the phone close to the headphones (in my shirt pocket...).  The same headphones work flawlessy with my PC. Experimentally, checking at home how far I can go before getting drop-outs I have a lot more range with the PC (at least 8 metres) than with the phone (3 meters tops), so I conclude that the emission level of the headphones could be insufficient (the other hypothesis is that the phone isn't sensitive enough to get the return signals from the headphones).

Is there any way to increase the BT emission level of the phone?

Running Android Pie.

Comment: Is the Bluetooth connector of the PC an small USB connector or an integrated one (e.g. in a notebook)? If it is the latter the difference is the antenna which is larger as the notebooks as more free space as a small smartphone.

Comment: @Robert Yes, it's an integrated one. But if the phone antenna is less efficient they can send more power to it....

Comment: I think the more sever problem is that Wifi uses the same frequencies and in the smartphone the antennas are more close to each other resulting in more disturbances. On a notebook they are usually far away from each other to minimize this type of problems. Disable Wifi on your phone or try [this guide](https://www.codejourney.net/2017/04/wifi-and-bluetooth-interference-diagnosing-and-fixing/) and check if that helps.

Comment: The problem is more acute when I am in the streets, normally farther from Wifi than at home. Will try next time I go out (in several weeks:))

Comment: So you are comparing the Bluetooth quality from your PC at home with the Bluetooth quality of your phone while walking somewhere around? Such a comparison does not necessarily mean that the smartphone has a bad Bluetooth quality. It may simple mean that the 2.4GHz band (which is used by dozens of protocols like Wifi, Bluetooth, ZigBee, wireless video transmission systems, ...) is so occupied out on the street that interruptions are inevitable.

Comment: I'm not the only one with BT headphones in the streets... And at home, that bathes in Wifi signals, the BT signal from the phone is much more disrupted than the one from the PC (tried the suggestion to disable wifi on the phone, BTW).

Comment: Then it may be that Bluetooth on the PC is a class 1 or 2 device (100/50m range) where as the Smartphone has only a class 3 Bluetooth device (max 10 meters). AFAIK the Bluetooth signal class can't be changed, it is a hardware property.